# Require login for specific templates

Tags: login

I have specific templates to request login.

I tried these three versions on functions.php file.

### `#`1

This is not working. I had to do  `add_action( 'wp_head', 'template_login_permit' );`

Because I put template directory? if I put 'wp_head', auth_redirect(); is not working.

```
function template_login_permit() {
if ( 
    is_page_template('templates/tpl-aa.php') || 
    is_page_template('templates/tpl-bb.php') ||  
    is_page_template('templates/tpl-cc.php') ||  
    is_page_template('templates/tpl-dd.php') ||  
    is_page_template('templates/tpl-ee.php') ||  
    is_page('shop')
    ) { 

    //echo "ok";
    //auth_redirect();
         if ( !is_user_logged_in() ) {
             //wp_redirect('/login');
             auth_redirect();
             echo "ok";
         }
}

}
   add_action( 'init', 'template_login_permit' );
```

### `#`2

`add_action( 'wp', 'login_redirect' );` 
wp are for all of templates, right? then how can I setup for only specific templates?

```
    // Redirect users who arent logged in...
function login_redirect() {
  // Current Page
  global $pagenow;
  // Check to see if user in not logged in and not on the login page
  if(!is_user_logged_in() && $pagenow != 'wp-login.php')
        // If user is, Redirect to Login form.
        //auth_redirect();
      echo "";
 }
 // add the block of code above to the WordPress template
  add_action( 'wp', 'login_redirect' );
```

### `#`3

This for just testing for custom Login page I have.

```
add_action('init','possibly_redirect');

function possibly_redirect(){
 global $pagenow;
if( 'wp-login.php' == $pagenow ) {
 wp_redirect('/login');
 exit();
   }
  }
```

---

Is there any way to request "login"(I have custom login page) for specific templates?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first function is just on the wrong hook. `init` is too soon for knowing which page template/page you are on because the query is not set up yet. The best hook for redirecting is usually `template_direct`. The following works for me:

```
function template_login_permit() {

    if (
        is_page_template('templates/tpl-aa.php') ||
        is_page_template('templates/tpl-bb.php') ||
        is_page_template('templates/tpl-cc.php') ||
        is_page_template('templates/tpl-dd.php') ||
        is_page_template('templates/tpl-ee.php') ||
        is_page('shop')
        ) {


            if ( !is_user_logged_in() ) {
                auth_redirect();
            }


    }

}
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'template_login_permit' );
```

Comment: Thanks so much. I have a short question. I have custom login 
  do you think it's good to put wp_redirect('/login'); instead of auth_redirect? I haven't finished the login page. so I can't really check now. If it is ok, It should be also redirect to previous page. anyway, thanks for ur time

Comment: `wp_redirect()` is fine, but redirecting back is another question. You can research that and then post another question if you need.